# create a notebook asset in watson studio using python

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson-studio, cloud-pak-for-data

I want to take a .ipynb that I downloaded from github (e.g. using "!git clone -b main --single-branch [https://github.com/Max-Jesch/watson-pipeline-test.git"](https://github.com/Max-Jesch/watson-pipeline-test.git%22)) to create a notebook asset in watson studio so I can run it using Watson pipelines

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.6.x?topic=lib-watson-studio-python) only describes how I can add assets with 'asset_type': 'data_asset'. What I need to do is create an asset with 'asset_type': 'notebook'. Is there any way to do this